# How to bind a single field data to combobox from observable collection in Silverlight MVVM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm

I have one doubt in Silverlight project that using MVVM architecture..

I have an ObservableCollection, the structure is this..

```
   internal static class EmployeeDataHelper
    {
        internal static ObservableCollection<Employee> CookEmployeesData()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Employee> sampleEmployees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            sampleEmployees.Add(new Employee("B007", "James Bond", 42, "Secret agent 007"));
            sampleEmployees.Add(new Employee("C002", "Charlie Jackson", 22, "Assistant to Bond"));
                     return sampleEmployees;
        }
    }
```

Here `<Employee>` is a class that contains get and set for the above values.
Now i need to bind the collection like that in combobox..

```
B007
C002 
etc..
```

like that..

How i can give the design coding for Combobox..

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 Grid.Column="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,12,0,0" 
 Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

if i give this means i not able to get the exact result.. please help me if u know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this , set `DisplayMemberPath`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbEmployee" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding sampleEmployees , Mode=TwoWay}"

 DisplayMemberPath="DisplaycolumnNameFromEmplyeeclass" >
```